# Setting permissions on Apigee BAAS

Tags: apigee

What's the best way to set permissions on objects in Apigee BAAS entities, collections in such a way that Users can edit what they create, and others can read them? There might be a case for Admins to be able to edit everything as well.

I asked a similar question here [Securing apigee baas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26073998/securing-apigee-baas) that was more around securing the app id/secret which would be needed to make the call to update permissions, but I was wondering if there is any best practice around doing this sort of thing from a mobile application.

My initial thought would still be the service callout (not sure how Apigee-127 which was mentioned in the previous question would be any different to a service callout directly to the BAAS as to me 127 looks like I'm just writing my apis in Node.js rather than using the edge console), but I don't know if there is an easier way in terms of securing all entities, in specific collections ,created by specific users? I guess I could add a created by column which I could check from an app perspective, but this wouldn't stop someone from potentially hitting the BAAS directly and retrieving this info unless permissions are also set at an entity level requiring a user access token.

Is it possible to secure the BAAS in such a way that only calls from Edge can hit the BAAS url?

Answer (score 0):

(Disclaimer: I have not tried this myself but here is a suggestion.)

API BaaS Automatically sets the path segment to the UUID of the currently authenticated user when $user is used. For example, if you sent a request with a valid access token for a user with UUID bd397ea1-a71c-3249-8a4c-62fd53c78ce7, the path /users/${user} would be interpreted as /users/bd397ea1-a71c-3249-8a4c-62fd53c78ce7, assigning the permission only to that user entity.

In this way,  through your application, you can set permission for each user, and each object as soon as the objects are created from your application. Assuming you have the user authenticated, of course.

Ref: http://apigee.com/docs/api-baas/content/using-permissions